# Are an Animagus' markings always the same?

Tags: harry-potter, animagi

When Prof. McGonagall turns into her cat form, she has markings on her face in the shape of her glasses. But what if she wasn't wearing them at the time? Would they still show up after she transformed? If she hung them from her gown, would the mark move from her face to her chest? Or what about when she gets a new pair of glasses that don't resemble her old ones? Would the shape/color of the mark change?

**Are an Animagus' markings always the same?**

If any of these are true, does that mean she would have to register each possibility/new prescription?

Comment: The pottermore article on Animagi has this to say; "*our Animagus may embody a distinguishing feature of your human self
An Animagus may seem the perfect disguise, but once you descend into your animal-self, there may be a distinguishing feature about you that stays. For example, Rita Skeeter’s beetle has little glasses-markings around the eyes, and in the famous case of Wormtail, both he and ‘Scabbers’ were missing a finger.*"

Comment: What I got from that is it *stays while in the current form*. If Wormtail got a prosthetic, would that show up on Scabbers as well? Or is his rat form forever going to miss a toe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, they probably are - or the Ministry of Magic has made a serious oversight..**

An Animagus is required to register with the Ministry, and their registration also includes notifying the Ministry of any identifiable markings their Animagus form has. There's no mention of them having to update the register if they change their markings, which a law-abiding and registered Animagus like McGonagall would do if it was required. Since registering these distinguishing markings is considered enough to keep track of the Animagus, this supports the theory, though is not conclusive proof, that these markings will not change.

> “Because … because people would know if Peter Pettigrew had been an Animagus. We did Animagi in class with Professor McGonagall. And I looked them up when I did my homework – the Ministry keeps tabs on witches and wizards who can become animals; there’s a register showing what animal they become, and their markings and things …” - <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 18 (Padfoot and Prongs)*</sup></sub>

Comment: While a good answer, its not necessarily an oversight. Criminals/convicts are often described with identifying marking a well (tattoos, birth marks, etc.). I am not sure if they have to update this when they exit the prison system though... and granted Animagi are not criminals... but that what it reminded me of.

Comment: @Skooba - Birthmarks tend to remain throughout one's life. Tattoos are _mostly_ permanent as well (yes, I know there's laser removal). Glasses can come & go (eyesight isn't _that_ bad, or wearer chooses contact lenses) or change styles on a whim as mentioned in the OP.